# Where can I find resources for a paper "Stability analysis of a novel DDE of HIV CD4+ T-cells"?

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, stability, mathematical-biology, delay-differential-equations

I am currently working on a the paper [NND]:

[image]

**Question:**
On page 4, equation 6 introduces a concept related to the infection rate within the context of the HIV model. Unfortunately, the paper does not provide much context or citation for further reading. I am seeking recommendations for journal articles or papers that explore the background and provide more technical details on this particular concept.

To provide some context, the concept is briefly mentioned in a paragraph preceding equation 6. It seems to be connected to The authors emphasises the importance of considering non-linear infection rates in HIV modeling.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could suggest relevant resources that can help me gain a deeper understanding of this concept and its applications in Mathematical Biology.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

**Reference**

[NND] Hoang Anh Ngo, Hung Dang Nguyen, Mehmet Dik "[Stability analysis of a novel Delay Differential Equation of HIV Infection of $\mathsf{CD4^+}$ $\mathsf{T}$-cells](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.00758.pdf)", pp. 32, [arXiv:2101.00758](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.00758) [q-bio.PE], 2021.